# Why does Ruby give a weird value?

Tags: ruby

I have this program that basically reverses a string and replaces some characters with other characters. However, when I perform puts dna1 it gives this value:DNA:0x007fdb4214a918

The value it should give is ATTGCC.

Here is the code:

```
class DNA
  def initialize (nucleotide)
     @nucleotide = nucleotide
  end
  def reverse_complement()

    puts nucleotide.reverse.tr("ATCG", "TAGC")
  end
  protected

  attr_reader :nucleotide
end
dna1 = DNA.new("ATTGCC")
puts dna1.reverse_complement

puts dna1

puts dna2 = dna1.reverse_complement
```

Comment: `puts` prints to `STDOUT` and returns `nil` remove puts to assign the string to `dna2` also you have no `inspect` method so it defaults to `Object#inspect` which is what you are referring to. if you defined `def inspect; nucleotide; end` then `puts dna1` would `puts` the current `nucleotide`

Answer (score 1):

```
# first you have
# ATTGCC
# then you reverse
# CCGTTA
# then you substitute
# CCGTTA
# A:T, T:A, C:G, G:C
# GGCAAT
```

It did exactly what you asked it to.

Now, you have an additional problem. You return the result of `#puts` in `reverse_complement,` so you never assign the computed value to `dna2`. Also, you assign the instance object to `dna1` but printing that isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

`dna1` is an instance of the class `DNA`.

`DNA:0x007fdb4214a918` shows the class name and the object id.

You need to print `nucleotide`

Do

```
class DNA
  attr_reader :nucleotide
```

You need it to be public and not protected.

and print it with

```
puts dna1.nucleotide
```

Similar issue with `dna2`. `puts` will return `nil` so you cannot print it.
You can remove the `puts` and just return the expression.

```
def reverse_complement()
  @nucleotide.reverse.tr("ATCG", "TAGC")
end
```

Edit:

Since you want to chain methods together

```
class DNA
  attr_reader :nucleotide

  def initialize(nucleotide)
    @nucleotide = nucleotide
  end

  def reverse_complement
    self.class.new(@nucleotide.reverse.tr("ATGC", "TAGC"))
  end

  def to_s
    @nucleotide
  end
end
```

Because you want to call `reverse_complement.reverse_complement`, you have to return a new class object using `self.class.new` than the string.

The `to_s` method lets you do `puts dna1` and get the string.

```
puts dna1.reverse_complement
#=> GGCAAT
puts dna1
#=> ATTGCC
```

For equality operations, you need to do

```
puts dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement.nucleotide == dna1.nucleotide
#=> true
```

Comment: Okay, I made the changes you suggested. However, why does this dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement == dna1 not return the value true?

Comment: `dna1` is an object not a string. You're instantiating a class with `DNA.new` and that is what is getting assigned to `dna1`. You'll need to do `dna1.reverse_complement.reverse_complement == dna1.nucleotide`

Comment: Did you put the `attr_reader :nucleotide` right after `class DNA` and not after `protected`?

Comment: Yes, I have it set up that way. It still gives that error.

Comment: Check my edit. You need to return a class in order to chain methods.